# Why does iOS Safari fire window focus event twice?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

I have the following code on a page:

```
var i = 0;
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) { 
  document.body.innerHTML = "Focus count = " + i++;
}, false);
```

On desktop this increments correctly (1,2,3 etc) when switching tabs (or any window blurring/focusing action)

However, when I switch tabs on ios safari the event appears to be firing twice (1,3,5,7 etc)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Face same problem on iOS 10.3.1

Comment: I have a similar issue on desktop Safari version 11.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

ATTOW the reason is unknown, but this *is* a known issue in Webkit:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179990

From above:

> With two or more text inputs on a form, switching focus by click from
>   one to another sometimes causes an extra focus/blur to fire.